# Fill next column in when first colum not null php Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

First time I have asked a question on here so I will try to explain as best I can. Apologies it's not the correct way of asking.

I have a table that has 7 columns and they are as follows

- Column 1 - ID (Primary)
- Column 2 - Postcode
- Column 3 - Lat (Latitude)
- Column 4 - Lng (Longitude)
- Column 5 - Supplier One
- Column 6 - Supplier Two
- Column 7 - Supplier Three.

What I want is to be able to have a form which has two options. THe first one being the Postcode and the Second being a Supplier.

I already know how to produce the form with drop down list but I am unsure of the post to the database. What I want to achieve is if you Select say postcode AB1 and a supplier it checks to see if column 5 is empty. If it is it stores it. If it is not then store in Column 6 and so on until it can store it if all columns are filled then message back saying all columns are filled in that row (probably a more use friend message but I can work that one out later).

Any help is much appreciated. Newbie here so sorry if I am asking a dumb question. I have checked to see if I can see a topic already but cant seem to find an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code,make changes according to your requirements:

$t1=SupplierOne;$t2=SupplierTwo;$t3=SupplierThree;
`for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
    $query="select t".$i." from tablename where Postcode='AB1'";
    $result=mysqli_query($query);
    if($result->num_rows==0){
        $query1="insert into (t".$i.") VALUES('data') where Postcode='AB1'";
        mysqli_query($query1);

    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, things will become much easier if proper 1:N relation was used. This is obviously a one `location` to many `suppliers` relation, which should be implemented with 2 tables (`suppliers` referencing `locations`).

This way you will not have to add conditions when INSERTing a supplier to a location. Also, no "all columns are filled" message is needed.